# React Native Navigator- routes not rendering until after the first navigation push?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I've just started playing around with React Native and I'm a relative newbie.  I'm having an issue using the `Navigator` component and I'm completely at a loss as to what's going on.

I'm trying to set up a simple master/detail flow.  The first screen is just a ListView with a few cells, and tapping on a cell pushes a detail screen.  The detail screen has static text telling you the index you just tapped and a button to pop back to the master screen.

However I'm getting completely weird behavior-- the detail screens for every cell (except the first) fail to render initially.  The navigator just transitions to a blank screen.  But if I push the first detail screen (which renders correctly), then pop it, then try to push again, the rest of the screens then proceed to work fine as intended.

Here is my code:

index.ios.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

//the navigation routes
const routes = [
  {title: 'Main View', index: 0}, //the main screen with the list view
  {title: 'Detail View 1', index: 1},
  {title: 'Detail View 2', index: 2},
  {title: 'Detail View 3', index: 3},
];

import MainList from './MainList'

export default class ReactNativePractice extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("master screen mounted")
  }

  //Navigator render scene function
  renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
    console.log("rendering route index: " + route.index)
      if (route.index === 0){ //the main list. pass in routes and navigator as props.
        return(
          <MainList
            nav={navigator}
            routes={routes}/>
        );
      }
      else{ //the detail screen. pass in route index and navigator as props.
        var indexNum = route.index
        return(
          <DetailView
            num={indexNum}
            nav = {navigator}/>
        );
      }
  }

  render() { //main render function. Set up the navigator
    return(
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={routes[0]}
        initialRouteStack={routes}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
}

//class for the detail view. Displays static text indicating the just-pressed index
//and a button to go back to the main list.
class DetailView extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{this.props.num}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {this.props.nav.pop()}}>
          <Text>Go back </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

//#####STYLESHEETS#####
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  row:{
    padding: 20,
    marginBottom: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativePractice', () => ReactNativePractice);
```

MainList.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const rows = [
  {id: 0, text: 'row 1'},
  {id: 1, text: 'row 2'},
  {id: 2, text: 'row 3'},
]
const rowHasChanged = (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged})
export default class MainList extends Component{

  state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows)
  }

  //row pressed function- push the corresponding navigation route.
  rowPressed = (rowData) =>{
    this.props.nav.push(this.props.routes[rowData.id+1]) //+1 because routes[0] is the main list view

  }

  renderRow = (rowData) => {
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.row}
        onPress={() => {this.rowPressed(rowData)}}
      >
        <Text>{rowData.text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ListView
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  row:{
    padding: 20,
    marginBottom: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
  },
});
```

I put in logs to the console that get called every time the navigator's renderScene function is called, and when the master component initially mounts. Inspecting my output on the console, here's what I get:

On app startup:

```
rendering route index: 0
rendering route index: 1
rendering route index: 2
rendering route index: 3
master screen mounted
```

On clicking any cell for the first navigation push (it doesn't matter which one):

```
rendering route index: 0
```

If I clicked specifically the first cell and now I'm trying to do the first navigation pop back to the master list view:

```
rendering route index: 0
```

After popping for the first time and now trying to push again (now everything works perfectly for every cell):

```
rendering route index: 0
rendering route index: [correct index]
```

Obviously there's something going on with the first push, because no matter what route index 0 is getting rendered and nothing else.  But I have no idea what I may be doing wrong, or why it seems to display the first screen at route index 1 fine anyway.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try `this.renderScene.bind(this)`?

Comment: @NaderDabit where would I put that, as the argument to the `renderScene` prop of the `Navigator` component? I just tried that and it makes no difference in behavior whatsoever.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're right that should make no difference! I'm not sure then, probably something to do with either styling or the `initialRouteStack` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following.

in `index.ios.js` `Navigator` component should be

```
    <Navigator
      style={{ flex:1 }}
      ref={(nav) => { navigator = nav; }}
      initialRoute={routes[0]}
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
    />
```

in `MainList.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const rows = [
  {id: 0, text: 'row 1'},
  {id: 1, text: 'row 2'},
  {id: 2, text: 'row 3'},
]
const rowHasChanged = (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged})
export default class MainList extends Component{

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows)
  };
}



  //row pressed function- push the corresponding navigation route.
  rowPressed = (rowData) =>{
    this.props.nav.push(this.props.routes[rowData.id+1]) //+1 because routes[0] is the main list view

  }

  renderRow = (rowData) => {
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.row}
        onPress={() => {this.rowPressed(rowData)}}
      >
        <Text>{rowData.text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ListView
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  row:{
    padding: 20,
    marginBottom: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, and in fact because of this I was able to pinpoint what was causing the issue, as mentioned in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Santosh Sharma's answer I've actually pinpointed the problem.  For some reason, passing both `initialRoute` and `initialRouteStack` to the `Navigator` was causing this issue.  If I simply pass in `initialRoute` and leave out `initialRouteStack` it works perfectly, on the first and subsequent pushes.  Anyone have any insight to the reason for this?